# how to increase width of an image while using position:relative

Tags: html, css, image

Here is the code:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" height="250">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background: url('image path goes here';); width: 300px; height: 250px; position: relative;">
<p style="width: 180px; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 35px; position: absolute;">My TEXT goes here....</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I am i need to increase the width of the image OR need to left-indent the image.

How can I do that ?

I have tried giving the width directly.. But it's not working...

Any advice or suggestion will be thankful and grateful..

Comment: In my opinion you can use image instead background and if you want to display content above image use z-index in that case. define image width and height 100%. It''' work dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using image as background of the parent div. If you want to just change the size of image you should use img tag. Something like the example below

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" height="250" width="300">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div >
                <img style="float:left;" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/03bc7f86de865926a1cb5036198d00a0?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" width="150px" height="125px" /></div>
<p style=" display: block; width: 280px; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 35px; position: relative;">We understand you want to choose benefits that suit you and your life. And we regularly review things so we're always offering benefits you say you want to see.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS3 background-size property.

```
.myelement {
    background-size: 275px 125px; /* input your values here */
}
```

Alternatively you could make yourimage inline instead of being the background of a DIV and size it using regular width and height that way.

A couple of points about the code you have posted:

1. Tables should only be used to display tabular data and not for simple layour purposes.
2. You have no closing DIV tag.

Comment: @VladislavQulin - Correct. The OP didn't however specify any browser requirements so I didn't feel the need to specifically mention that but I did say that it was CSS3 and I credit the OP with having some basic knowledge that CSS3 is for new browsers only.